# Doing file search from Google drive

Tags: javascript

I am a fresh programming student and currently studying Google APIs. I wanted to build a search bar into a custom webpage to do file search from my own Google drive files/folders i.e. takes the user input and shows the result `inHtml()`. I got the idea from Google developers side, but don't know how to implement that to my own search bar.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it

I did hours of research but did not find anything about what I am looking for.

Here is my messy code:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="inp" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<button id="srbtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="searchResult()">Submit</button>
<p id="dsp"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function doGet(input) {
  var input = document.getElementById("inp").value;
  var results = DriveApp.getFolderById('My_Drive_ID').searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Results: <br /><br /><ul>');
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var file = results.next();
    output.append('<li><a href="' + file.getUrl() + '">' + file.getName() + '</a></li>');
  }
  function searchResult(result){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=doGet(e);
  }
```

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: you are mixing server side inside client side code. revise those concepts.

Comment: @ZigMandel Could you please give a sample for client-side? Thanks.

Comment: You will not find what you are looking for on StackOverflow because it is not a copy/paste code exchange.